# Does an antenna emit EM radiation in all directions?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, dipole, antennas

You know how an antenna works? It creates EM fields and oscilates them so that it creates  electromagnetic fields...Well does that electromagnetic wave travel in a straight line or spread out circularly? and Why?

Comment: http://www.antenna-theory.com/basics/radpattern.php

Comment: google beam pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oscillating electrons (AC current) in a linear dipole antenna introduce transverse components into the preexisting E fields (of the electrons), and magnetic fields which wrap around the current. The resulting radiation is strong in a direction at right angles to the current, and drops to zero in a direction parallel to the current.

Answer (score 0):

The shape of the radiation field around an antenna depends very sensitively on the shape and orientation of the antenna itself, and on things like ground proximity. Careful design allows the antenna to radiate in all directions equally, or in one direction, or in two directions, as desired.

The experts on the amateur radio stack exchange can furnish detailed explanations and standard design rules for this.